# Datatables fnUpdate on a row that is out of view due to pagination?

Tags: jquery, pagination, datatables

The following function works fine on the rows visible on the current page of my datatable. How do I get it to work on a row currently hidden by pagination?

```
var table = $('.datatable').dataTable();
var row = table.fnGetPosition($('#'+data.id).closest('tr')[0]);
var value = table.fnGetData(table.fnGetPosition($('#'+data.id).closest('tr')[0]),11);
if (value == '') {
    value = cid;
} else {
    value = value+','+cid;
}
table.fnUpdate(value, row, 11);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can achieve this using fnGetNodes(), here's is a reference to the documentation https://datatables.net/api

and here's a example on fiddle for ya http://jsfiddle.net/mxfvLjnb/

ill put the code here just for better reference

```
var oTable = $('#example').dataTable({"sPaginationType": "full_numbers"});

var rows = oTable.fnGetNodes();
for(var i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
{
    oTable.fnUpdate('X', rows[i], 4);
}
```

hope it helps you

Answer (score 2):

Since DataTables 1.10+ might not support `fnGetNodes()` as [mentioned](https://datatables.net/api) on the API landing page itself, instead now you can use [`rows().nodes()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().nodes())

For updating a particular row, you can use a [`row-selector`](https://datatables.net/reference/type/row-selector) and then
for updating specific cell of that particular row, you can use [`cell().data()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/cell().data())

Aggregating the above mentioned modifications, the code for your example changes to the following:

```
//Notice the 'd' replaced by 'D' in dataTable() for Datatables v1.10+
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
var row = table.row('#' + data.id).node();
var value = table.cell(row, 11).data();

if (value == '') {
  value = cid;
}
else {
  value += ',' + cid;
}
table.cell(row, 11).data(value).draw();
```